# is a LOCK TABLE needed for `UPDATE tbl SET col = col + 1`?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mariadb, flock

lets say that `col` is 0, and 100 clients is trying to increase it by 1 at the exact same time, is the LOCK TABLE needed here?

```
LOCK TABLE tbl;
UPDATE tbl SET col = col + 1;
UNLOCK TABLE;
```

or can i just do

```
UPDATE tbl SET col = col + 1;
```

and be sure that col becomes 100? (eg that mariadb makes sure none of them reads the same value twice~)

i'm basically trying to do the equivalent of this php code

```
$fp = fopen("counter.txt", "r+b");
flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
$number = (int) stream_get_contents($fp);
$number += 1;
rewind($fp);
fwrite($fp, (string) $number);
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);
```

but with a database instead of a text file

and i doubt there's a difference between MariaDB and MySQL on this one, but if there is, i'd like to learn about it, so tagging both (as an anecdote, i'm using MySQL at work, and MariaDB at home~)

Comment: it is not a column that you are updating it is a **row**, so when you update the row lock is in place(innodb). but you still have to retrieve it

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "be sure that col becomes 100".

Comment: @RickJames in this code, do you understand why the final number is kindof random?:  https://pastebin.com/i1QfF3mg  (try it yourself if you'd like)

Comment: @hanshenrik - Does the code check for errors at every step?

Comment: @RickJames no it didn't, but now it does, and the results are still the same: https://pastebin.com/9s516Cmz - this happens when several children reads the same number simultaneously, or lets say that the number is 99, and child1 is about to write 100 and has already written 1, then child2 reads both bytes and now reads 19 instead of 99 or 100, then child2 would increase it to 20 instead of 101... (that last part about half-written reads would never happen in mysql, but the double-read? idk)

Comment: @hanshenrik - Are you referring to the flock locking?  Or InnoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use MyISAM, use InnoDB.  Do not use `LOCK TABLES` with InnoDB.

In no situation do you need any kind of a lock for a single query.  A query has an implicit lock.  (MyISAM locks the table; InnoDB locks the row(s).)

Locks / transactions are needed when you have *multiple* statements that need to be kept together "atomically".  Notice how your example does both a read and a write, plus doing something with the value read.

The equivalent in InnoDB (in pseudo-code):

```
START TRANSACTION;
$num = SELECT num FROM tbl WHERE id=1  FOR UPDATE;
$num = $num + 1;
UPDATE tbl SET num = $num;
COMMIT;
```

True, `UPDATE table SET num = num + 1` does the same thing atomically, but it does not let you do anything else with the value of `num`.

MariaDB has a `RETURNS` clause in some cases.  There is `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.  But these are limited exceptions to the rule that you should really think in terms of multi-statement transactions if you expect to have multiple threads messing with the same data.

Answer (score 0):

As a starter: your query seems to be missing a `WHERE` clause, that specifies which row should be updated. Presumably, you would use a primary key column for this, say `id` - for example:

```
UPDATE tbl SET col = col + 1 WHERE id = 1;
```

Now, assuming that you have many concurrent processes running this query at the same time, then I would not recommend manually locking the row. Instead, let the database manage the concurrency for you. It will actually lock the row for you under the hood, and execute the concurrent queries sequentially, handing the row over the next transaction as the previous one is commited. If the intial value is `0` and there are `100` concurrent processes, you will end up with `100` as a final value.